# How to check what number array a string is in. using swift

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, dictionary

How do i get the textfield input to return the array index that the text is, without doing it manually like i did below, because i will have hundreds of items in the array(the colors are just an example)?

```
@IBOutlet weak var label:UILabel

@IBOutlet weak var textField:UITextField


var arrayOfColors:[String] = ["Blue", "Black", "Yellow", "Purple"]


if textFeild.text == "Blue" {

println("array index 0")
}

else if textFeild.text == "Yellow" {

println("array index 3")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you an optional, so be prepared to deal with nil if necessary

```
find(arrayOfColors, textFeild.text!) //returns the index (0) if text is "Blue"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate through the array and just print the index or indexes, if you have the same value multiple times.

The `find` function will only return the first occurrence of the searched text.

```
var arrayOfColors:[String] = ["Blue", "Black", "Yellow", "Purple", "Yellow"]

for var i = 0; i < arrayOfColors.count; i++ {
    if arrayOfColors[i] == textField.text { 
        println("The index is \(i)") // assuming textField.text is "Yellow" it will print "The index is 2" and "The index is 4"
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is more inefficient than it needs to be. Plus, "Yellow" should probably be text field's text.

Comment: Why do you say that this answer is inefficient? Yes `"Yellow"` should be modified to `textField.text`, but then I couldn't have said that it will print index to be 2

Comment: Because you can use the find function instead for a more efficient search.

Comment: Yes, but what if I have this array `["Blue", "Black", "Yellow", "Purple", "Yellow"]` that `find` function will not return the second index for "Yellow", which I might need, so it depends on the context of what's needed.

Comment: OK, that's fair. I would specify that in your answer...  But also, "Yellow" should be changed to textField.text.